# locally committing to git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git project that contains a git submodule that I cloned from a public **read-only** repository (i.e. I cannot push to that repository). Is it possible to commit to that submodule? Here's how I tried to do this

```
[main]$ cd sub
[sub]$ git checkout master
[sub]$ echo test > new-file
[sub]$ git add new-file
[sub]$ git commit -m 'added a new file'
[sub]$ cd ..
[main]$ git add sub
[main]$ git push origin
```

So far so good. Now the problem is when I go to another computer and I do the following:

```
[main]$ git pull
[main]$ git submodule update
```

but it fails with `fatal: reference is not a tree: af232...`. I thought that this would work because when I do `git push origin` in main it seems that it pushes all objects for the submodules as well (after all they are in main's .git directory). But apparently, when the second computers pulls, it does not receive these new objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have pushed the submodule change in the super-project, but you have not pushed the actual change that happened in the submodule (`git push origin` doesn't push submodule changes, only its commit SHA1.). This is not something you can do since it is a read-only repo.

What you can do is to change the URL of the submodule to a repository of your own, push the change to it, and commit and push the URL change in the super-project.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's exactly what I am trying to avoid here. If I do that then I will not be able to follow the "upstream" repository (the one where I cloned the submodule from).

Comment: There's no other way to do it if you don't have write access. You can still follow upstream by pulling from your clone and pushing to your mirror repo.